# Use the same piece of Code in multiple functions in Laravel 5

Tags: php, function, laravel

I have this code and I want to use the first 10-15 lines in every function of my Controller, how can i do it without copy-paste everywhere?

```
public function fac(){
    $homebanking=Auth::user();
    $cliente=$homebanking->cliente();
    $nome=$cliente->nome;

    $id=$cliente->id;
    //dd($cliente->contas()->get());
    $i=0;
    $contas=$cliente->contas();
    foreach ($cliente->contas()->get() as $conta){
        $idcontas[$i]=($conta->id);
        $i=$i+1;
    }

    $homebanking=Auth::user();
    $cliente=$homebanking->cliente();
    $nome=$cliente->nome;

    return view('hbpages.fac',compact('nome'));
}

public function presta(){
    $homebanking=Auth::user();
    $cliente=$homebanking->cliente();
    $nome=$cliente->nome;

    $id=$cliente->id;
    //dd($cliente->contas()->get());
    $i=0;
    $contas=$cliente->contas();
    foreach ($cliente->contas()->get() as $conta){
        $idcontas[$i]=($conta->id);
        $i=$i+1;
    }

    $homebanking=Auth::user();
    $cliente=$homebanking->cliente();
    $nome=$cliente->nome;

    return view('hbpages.presta',compact('nome'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not *entirely* sure what you're doing here, but you can always add the bulk of the code as a new function and call with `$this->` from the first two, if you're looking for a quick abstraction:

```
public function fac()
{
    $nome = $this->allTheStuff();

    return view('hbpages.fac',compact('nome'));
}

public function allTheStuff()
{
    $homebanking=Auth::user();
    $cliente=$homebanking->cliente();
    $nome=$cliente->nome;

    $id=$cliente->id;

    $i=0;
    $contas=$cliente->contas();
    foreach ($cliente->contas()->get() as $conta){
        $idcontas[$i]=($conta->id);
        $i=$i+1;
    }
    $homebanking=Auth::user();
    $cliente=$homebanking->cliente();

    return $cliente->nome;
}
```

Comment: `$nome` should equal `$cliente->nome`, as you had it before - we're just asking `allTheStuff()` to run the code block for us and then `return $cliente->nome` so it can be used in the view.

Comment: yeah , just what i thinked but what if i want all the variables i use in the allTheStuff() function to be sent to a view? like the $idcontas ?